# Why Push notifications sample_push.php file is not running in Ubuntu?

Tags: iphone, ubuntu, push-notification

When i run this file in my ubuntu localhost, it's not run. But on other ubuntu systems it runs. I think some libraries i am missing. Guys please suggest me some configuration libraries.

```
<?php

    date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Rome');

    error_reporting(-1);
    require_once 'ApnsPHP/Autoload.php';

    $push =new ApnsPHP_Push(ApnsPHP_Abstract::ENVIRONMENT_SANDBOX,
                            'server_certificates_bundle_sandbox.pem');

    $push->setRootCertificationAuthority('entrust_root_certification_authority.pem');
    $push->connect();

    $message = new ApnsPHP_Message('1e82db91c7ceddd72bf33d74ae052ac9c84a065b35148ac401388843106a7485');
    $message->setCustomIdentifier("Message-Badge-3");

    $message->setBadge(3);
    $message->setText('Hello APNs-enabled device!');

    $message->setSound();
    $message->setCustomProperty('acme2', array('bang', 'whiz'));

    $message->setCustomProperty('acme3', array('bing', 'bong'));
    $message->setExpiry(30);

    $push->add($message);
    $push->send();

    $push->disconnect();
    $aErrorQueue = $push->getErrors();

    if (!empty($aErrorQueue)) 
    {   
        var_dump($aErrorQueue);
    }

?>
```

Comment: You must get a PHP error, either on screen or in the log. If not turn logging on and tell us the result!!!

Comment: Yes it's php error because same code is running on other ubuntu system but not at my system. Could you please tell me how can check log message

Comment: http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/error_log-defines-file-where-script-errors-logged/